# URL directory IIS 6

Tags: .net, url, iis, dns

Quick question, possibly a no brainer. How is this a URL:

wwww.yahoo.com/index.aspx/somefile.aspx

In the construction of directories and such I don't get how the above URL is possible since the main domain is supposed to stop at index.aspx. I mean there is no folder on the server named index.aspx.

The link above obviously doesn't work, I'm using an example from my site which has a link like above. I'm running .Net and IIS 6 if that helps.

Comment: There's nothing at all preventing a directory to be named Index.aspx.

Comment: Okay but the thing is on our server, there is no folder/directory named index.aspx so how is this happening I want to get rid of this URL.

Comment: I have no idea how that is happening. You would need to share some code for that.

Answer (score 0):

this can be accomplished use Url rewrites.

Comment: I think I may not have mentioned. I want to rid my site of this URL, for one I'm unsure of how this even being created secondly I want to rid the site of this URL, but I have no idea of where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You create a folder in your web project called `index.aspx` and then add a page to this folder called `somefile.aspx`. Works perfectly well.

Comment: Sure. Problem is I have no project/folder/directory called index.aspx and I want to get rid of this URL altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Somewhere in your code, someone or something is programmatically creating that URL. It code be a response.redirect, a url rewrite, or an incorrect configuration of forms authentication in your web.config. I would look at web.config first, then search for cases of response.redirect.